Dubrovnik airport doesn't support online check-in. Does it mean that I should be ready to pay for check-in at the airport?
I am using LOT airline. I managed to check in on the airline's website from Warsaw to Dubrovnik, but not the other way around.

This flight is not supported.

LOT's website has a hint: If you were able to log into the check-in panel, but did not receive your boarding pass, check-in at the airport.
Website of Dubrovnik can't find my ticket.
Does it mean that I should be ready to pay for check-in at the airport?

Why is it that you think you'll need to pay?

@MJeffryes Some airlines like Ryanair charge for airport checkins.

Note: check-in are managed by airlines or ground services paid by airlines (usually by two or more companies), so very seldom by airport staff (but when they provide such services). So check with your airline -- The site you linked, may just connect to the few global reservation/ticketing systems, but some airlines are getting away from them (they costs too much).

@lambshaanxy I would hope the fee could be waived if the airline refused to allow you to check in online.

If you cannot check in online, then the airline will invariably waive any possible fees. In the case of Ryanair they tell you to contact them if you have technical issues. Since LOT tell you to check in at the airport we can assume there will be no fee for this

The LOT site points to the Dubrovnik airport page linked in the question. Did you try with the various possible references (ticket number or confirmation number, or frequent flyer number if you have one registered on that ticket)? Did you double check the first/last name order, and that you typed it exactly like on the ticket?

Yes, I tried all options in this website. Thank you for pointing.

Warsaw is a middle place for us. All check-in done very smooth for two persons. Only Dubrovnik airport doesn't provide API way to do it (my assumption) Tomorrow morning I'll check how to check-in in the airport. I am interested to ask in person what the reason or state.

I think people from the whole plane were in the in-person check-in queue.
The check-in person did a very precise check for us non EU citizens.
We didn't pay for anything, but I would appreciate if the flying company would inform travelers in advance that online check-in isn't an option at all.
Thanks for all comments, you have lessened my worries.

It's really weird that they've bothered given that Dubrovnik is in the Schengen area. Always supper annoying to be checked on Schengen flights.
